# Benchmarking the flutter_osm_plugin and mapmyindia_gl plugin

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap, mapmyindia-api

I am new to Flutter and trying to integrate the map into my application, I would like to hear valuable thoughts from experts. [Google Maps is very expensive]

Which is good to go and why?